# $\|(A_n-z)^{-1} - (A-z)^{-1}\|\to 0\;\Rightarrow\; \|e^{-tA_n}-e^{-tA}\|\to 0$ for general $C_0$ semigroups?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

In short, the question is whether norm-resolvent convergence implies operator-norm convergence of the assocoated semigroups. More specifically, assume the following:

1. The $A_n$ generate contraction semigroups for all $n$,
2. $A$ generates a contraction semigroup,
3. One has $\|(A_n+1)^{-1} - (A+1)^{-1}\|\to 0$ in operator norm.

Then, can one get anything better than strong convergence for the associated semigroups (preferably operator norm convergence for some fixed t>0)?

The answer is relatively simple for *analytic* semigroups, since in that case one has an integral formula that expresses the semigroup in terms of the resolvent. For general $C_0$ semigroups, it's much less obvious...

Comment: In general, no, at least not without some uniformity with respect to z. Note that $(tA-z)^{-1}$ is continuous in the operator norm for $t>0$ and any $z$ where it is defined. But $e^{-tA}$ need not be continuous in operator norm.